# Start code execution at 00:08:15 instead of 00:08:00

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet

In "ThisWorkbook", paste :

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    'Stop execution when workbook closes
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.OnTime Heure, "Calcul", , False
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
     'start execution at 8 AM when workbook opens
     If Hour(Now()) < 8 & Minute(Now()) < 5 Then
         ' If it is before 8 AM
         Application.OnTime Int(Now()) + TimeSerial(8, 5, 0), "Calcul"
     Else
         ' Otherwise begin 8 AM the next day
         Application.OnTime Int(Now()) + 1 + TimeSerial(8, 5, 0), "Calcul"
     End If
End Sub
```

In a module, paste :

```
Public Heure As Date

Sub Calcul()
    Heure = Now + TimeValue("00:15:00")
    Application.OnTime Heure, "Calcul"
    With [B65536].End(xlUp)(2)
        .Item(1, 1) = [A1]
        .Item(1, 3) = [C1]
    End With
End Sub
```

I want this code to start at 00:08:15 instead of 00:08:00. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following lines of code control when your "Calcul" function starts:

```
Application.OnTime Int(Now()) + TimeSerial(8, 5, 0), "Calcul"
...
Application.OnTime Int(Now()) + 1 + TimeSerial(8, 5, 0), "Calcul"
```

This currently runs your code at 08:05:00 (not 00:08:00!). To make them run at 08:15:00, change them to:

```
Application.OnTime Int(Now()) + TimeSerial(8, 15, 0), "Calcul"
...
Application.OnTime Int(Now()) + 1 + TimeSerial(8, 15, 0), "Calcul"
```